# What is the Big O complexity for this division algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

```
Input: Two n-bit integers x and y, where x ≥ 0, y ≥ 1.
Output: The quotient and remainder of x divided by y.
if  x = 0, then return (q, r) := (0, 0);
q := 0;  r := x; 
while (r ≥ y) do
    { q := q + 1;
      r := r – y};
return (q, r);
```

I have obtained the Big O complexity as O(n^2) but a friends says it is O(2^n) where n is the number of bits as the input size

Please provide explanation

Comment: Not clear why you think it's only "n iterations".

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I removed the statement, I do not think that is true.

Comment: Kinda fishy that two people have asked for an analysis of identical pseudocode in such a short time span: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269956/time-complexity-of-iterative-division-algorithm

Comment: Would you share your / a friend's thougths that led to the assumption of O(n^2) and O(2^n)?

Comment: @wLui155 Probably that's the friend that they mentioned :-D

Comment: @wLui155 that's another colleague, who is confused by this

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have provided my solution in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of iterations of the while-loop is exactly `floor(x/y)`. Each iteration takes `n` operations, because that is the complexity of the subtraction `r - y`.

Hence the complexity of the algorithm is `n * floor(x/y)`. However, we want to express the complexity as a function of `n`, not as a function of `x` and `y`.

Thus the question becomes: how does `floor(x/y)` relate to `n`, in the worst case?

The biggest value that can be obtained for `x/y` when `x` and `y` are two nonnegative `n`-digits numbers, and `y >= 1`, is obtained by taking the biggest possible value for x, and the smallest possible value for y.

- The biggest possible value for `x` is `x = 2**n - 1` (all bits of `x` are 1 in its binary representation);
- The smallest possible value for `y` is `y = 1`.

Hence the biggest possible value for x/y is `x/y = 2**n - 1`.

The time-complexity of your division algorithm is `O(n * 2**n)`, and this upper-bound is achieved when `x = 2**n - 1` and `y = 1`.

Comment: Why correlate Big O with worst case? Isn't Big O calculated when input size to infinity?

Comment: @AzamM We want to find the smallest function `f` of `n` such that, for some constant `C`, when `n` is big enough, the time of execution of the algorithm is always less than `C * f(n)`. Because of this "always less" condition, we have to consider the worst-case.

Answer (score 0):

> My proposed solution:
>
> When calculating Big O complexity we need to take n->infinity, where n is > input size, we have 3
> possibilities:
>
> 1. x & y both become infinity when n->infinity
> 2. y becomes infinity when n->infinity
> 3. x becomes infinity when n-> infinity
>
> We are interested only in case 3 here,
>
> (x – i * y ) < y,  i being the number of iterations
>
> also written as x/y < i + 1
>
> when x becomes infinity LHS(Left hand side) is infinity in this
> equation which implies RHS is infinity as well
>
> So as n-> infinity the number iterations becomes equal to n
>
> Hence, the complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: Your argument makes sense up to *"also written as x/y < i + 1"*. Then the two following sentences don't really make sense to me: *"when x becomes infinity LHS(Left hand side) is infinity in this equation which implies RHS is infinity as well.

So as n-> infinity the number iterations becomes equal to n"*

Comment: @Stef x/y < i + 1 is just the rearrangement of the equation to denote the division at every iteration i. And regarding the LHS/RHS, the relation is < so if LHS is inifinity, RHS is definitely infinity.

Comment: Yes, I agree with all of the above. But how do you jump from that to *"So as n-> infinity the number iterations becomes equal to n"*?

Comment: @Stef that (n->infinity) is the initial premise that led to case 3, and i being the iterations.